Reproducing Python/Programming Code Blocks with modification
I want to be able to reproduce this environment within the context of exam correction.
One clue I found is the usage of the bclogo package.
https://ctan.org/pkg/bclogo
Howerver, I would like to include the highlighted Python code as seen here, and I want to include indentation lines and color them according to the scope (indentation level).

Coloring the lines of an algorithm:

Code of the colored Algorithm:
\pdfoutput=1
\usepackage[linesnumbered,titlenumbered,ruled,vlined,resetcount,algosection]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\title{MWE}
\maketitle
\section{Algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{3-SAT in polynomial time}
    \label{alg:hs}
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \KwIn{List of clauses}
    \KwOut{The clauses are satisfiable}
    \SetKwProg{Fn}{Function}{ is}{end}
    \Fn{\textsc{IsSatisfiable}($C$)} {
    
        \color{red} %<- my best attempt
        $k\gets 0$ \;
        \For {$i = 1$ \bf{to} $|C|$}
        {
            $c_i \gets $ $i$-th clause \;
            $L \gets$ list of literals of $c_i$ \;
            $k\gets f(k, L)$ \tcp{a miracle in polynomial time}
        }
        \color{black} %<- go back to color black
        
        \If {$k$ is even} {
            \Return true
        }
        \Else {
            \Return false
        }
        
    }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}


Welcome. // Ok, to try and improve your code we have to A) retype it, B) guess about your preamble, C) hope for the best we met your situation. That's why responses will be more helpful when you post relevant code instead of code-screenshots. Kindly see here to create what we'd like to see here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137 . Thank you

@MS-SPO, Unfortunately I do not have the code of the image above as I'm trying to reproduce it. I only have the source code to the bottom one. I have added the source code. Please let me know if anything else is required in order to be able to reproduce it. Thank you.

For the Python code, here is a solution with the package piton which requires the use of LuaLaTeX (but no external program).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{piton}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{bleupyth}{rgb}{0.2157,0.436,0.6172}
\definecolor{jaunpyth}{rgb}{1,0.8157,0.25}

\newcommand{\PythonLogo}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.004]
  \begin{scope}[,yscale=-1]
    \fill[bleupyth] (41.1090,0.0000) .. controls (20.0860,0.0000) and
    (21.3980,9.1170) ..  (21.3980,9.1170) -- (21.4220,18.5620) --
    (41.4840,18.5620) -- (41.4840,21.3980) -- (13.4530,21.3980)
    .. controls (13.4530,21.3980) and (0.0000,19.8710)
    .. (0.0000,41.0860) .. controls (0.0000,62.3010) and
    (11.7420,61.5470) .. (11.7420,61.5470) -- (18.7500,61.5470) --
    (18.7500,51.7030) .. controls (18.7500,51.7030) and
    (18.3710,39.9610) ..  (30.3050,39.9610) .. controls
    (42.2380,39.9610) and (50.2030,39.9610) ..  (50.2030,39.9610)
    .. controls (50.2030,39.9610) and (61.3830,40.1410) ..
    (61.3830,29.1560) .. controls (61.3830,18.1720) and
    (61.3830,10.9920) ..  (61.3830,10.9920) .. controls
    (61.3830,10.9920) and (63.0820,0.0000) ..  (41.1090,0.0000) --
    cycle(30.0470,6.3520) .. controls (32.0430,6.3520) and
    (33.6560,7.9650) .. (33.6560,9.9610) .. controls (33.6560,11.9570)
    and (32.0430,13.5700) .. (30.0470,13.5700) .. controls
    (28.0510,13.5700) and (26.4380,11.9570) .. (26.4380,9.9610)
    .. controls (26.4380,7.9650) and (28.0510,6.3520)
    .. (30.0470,6.3520) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[shift={(81,-81)},xscale=-1]
    \fill[jaunpyth] (41.1090,0.0000) .. controls (20.0860,0.0000) and
    (21.3980,9.1170) ..  (21.3980,9.1170) -- (21.4220,18.5620) --
    (41.4840,18.5620) -- (41.4840,21.3980) -- (13.4530,21.3980)
    .. controls (13.4530,21.3980) and (0.0000,19.8710)
    .. (0.0000,41.0860) .. controls (0.0000,62.3010) and
    (11.7420,61.5470) .. (11.7420,61.5470) -- (18.7500,61.5470) --
    (18.7500,51.7030) .. controls (18.7500,51.7030) and
    (18.3710,39.9610) ..  (30.3050,39.9610) .. controls
    (42.2380,39.9610) and (50.2030,39.9610) ..  (50.2030,39.9610)
    .. controls (50.2030,39.9610) and (61.3830,40.1410) ..
    (61.3830,29.1560) .. controls (61.3830,18.1720) and
    (61.3830,10.9920) ..  (61.3830,10.9920) .. controls
    (61.3830,10.9920) and (63.0820,0.0000) ..  (41.1090,0.0000) --
    cycle(30.0470,6.3520) .. controls (32.0430,6.3520) and
    (33.6560,7.9650) .. (33.6560,9.9610) .. controls (33.6560,11.9570)
    and (32.0430,13.5700) .. (30.0470,13.5700) .. controls
    (28.0510,13.5700) and (26.4380,11.9570) .. (26.4380,9.9610)
    .. controls (26.4380,7.9650) and (28.0510,6.3520)
    .. (30.0470,6.3520) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}} 

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewPitonEnvironment{Python}{}
  { 
    \noindent \PythonLogo\newline \nobreak
    \leavevmode 
    \hspace* { 7.4 pt } 
    \vrule width 1pt 
    \hspace* { 5 pt } 
    \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \linewidth - 12.4 pt }
    \begin { minipage } { \l_tmpa_dim }
  }
  { \end { minipage } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{Python}
class PCFS(StratégieOrdonnancement):
    def elire(sef):
        p = min(selp.fp.data, key = lambda p : p.taP)
        if p.taP <= self.horlogie:
            p.changerEtat("Elu")
\end{Python}

\end{document}

The code for the logo of Python has been taken here.

